# Create a merged map with list of maps

Tags: java, collections, stream

I'm new to java so seeking help from experts. any help would be much appreciated, and a scope for me to learn new things.

I want to create a List of maps(resultList) from a another list of maps(list) where a single map(keys) contains values which are keys to the list of maps(map1, map2, map3 ... So on). Like below example

```
Map<String, String> keys = new HashMap<>();
keys.put("Animal","Cow");
keys.put("Bird","Eagle");

Map<String, String> map1 =new HashMap<>();
map1.put("Cow","Legs");
m1.put("Eagle","Wings");

Map<String, String> map2 = new HasMap<>();
map2.put("Cow","Grass");
map2.put("Eagle","Flesh");

List<Map<String, String>> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add(map1);
list.add(map2); // there could be more

List<Map<String, String>> resultList= new ArrayList<>();
for(Map<String, String> eachMap: listOfMaps){
     Map<String, String> mergedMap = new HasMap<>();
     //help me here
}
```

Now I want values of first map(keys) as key to each new map(mergedMap) for the values of second map(map1) and third map(map2) and so on.

Required output should be like

```
{ Cow : Legs, Eagle : Wings }
{ Cow : Grass, Eagle : Flesh }
//more
```

Comment: Cow has to be a key for each new map. Not as key for multiple values in a single map

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way to do it using streams.

```
Collection<String> vals = keys.values();
resultList = list.stream()
    .map(eachMap -> vals.stream()
            .filter(eachMap::containsKey)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Function.identity(), eachMap::get)))
     .collect(Collectors.toList());
 
System.out.println(resultList);
```

Note: The `filter` checks if the value is present in the map before creating the map.

Comment: Can you please explain what for Function.identity() is. Understood everything except that part

Comment: It is a shorthand/alternative for the lambda expression `val -> val`.  Basically, it says to use the same value as the map's key (no transformation or mapping). For the map's value we are doing a lookup. `eachMap::get` when written as a lambda expression will be like `val -> eachMap.get(val)`.

Answer (score 1):

Loop through each map and for each map, loop through the values in the `keys` map and look it up into the current map and insert the result in the `mergedMap`. At the end of processing a map, add the `mergedMap` into the `resultList`.

```
for(Map<String, String> eachMap: list){
     Map<String, String> mergedMap = new HashMap<>();
     for (String val: keys.values()) {
        mergedMap.put(val, eachMap.get(val));
     }
     resultList.add(mergedMap);
}

System.out.println(resultList);
```

This assumes the values in the `keys` map will always be present in each of the maps. If not you have to check if the key is present before adding to the `mergedMap` (to avoid adding *null* values).